# Make a JPanel scale to fit width but keep a fixed height

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I have a `JPanel` which I'm placing inside of a `JScrollPane`. I am manually painting it using `paintComponent()`, since it's being used as a canvas, and I want the panel to automatically fit to the width of the scroll pane. I can then use `getWidth()` in the painting code to automatically scale to fit the container. However, I want to be able to manually set the preferred height so the I make use of the scroll pane's vertical scrolling capabilities.

What's the best way to do this? This would obviously still work if I was just able to get the width of the scroll pane in the painting code, but I don't want to break encapsulation too much with hacky code like `getParent()`.

Comment: Had you tried overriding the getPreferredSize(), the same way as you override your `paintComponent(...)`, just provide some arbitrary values, just make it return something like `return new Dimension(500, 700)`. Won't that solve your purpose ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw Same thing, I need to know the width of the scroll pane to actually paint my component properly (it scales). I can't just set the width to an arbitrary value.

Comment: What if then you write return (new Dimension([scroller.getWidth()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getWidth()), 700)) or else you can use [getViewportBorderBounds()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#getViewportBorderBounds()). Won't this solve the thingy, or I still missed something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let your panel implement Scrollable: the getScrollableTracksViewportWidth/Height control how the viewport handles the sizing in the horizontal/vertical dimension, respectively. A value of true indicates that the component is forced to the same size as viewport (that is, no scrolling in that direction), so getWidth() can be consistently used for scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I would get your paint code to use the horiz width of itself as the basis for painting.
Then set the scroll pane so it never scrolls horizontally, only vertically.
Is this good enough ? Seems too simple now I've typed it out !

Comment: Well, see, I need to know the width of the scroll pane to actually paint my component properly (it scales). So just not scrolling isn't really an option.

Comment: But you accepted an answer which tells you to do exactly that ! Hmmmmm weird